# How to avoid php escape string on online hosting?

Tags: php, pdo

When I type ***don't***, it save ***don\'t*** to database. I tested the code on wamp offline server and it save ***don't***. But when I test the code on online hosting, it save ***don\'t***. How to make online hosting don't use excape string?

Codes :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn_edit'])) { 
    $description = $_POST['description'];
}


$sql = "UPDATE expense 
    SET description=?
    WHERE spender_id=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $q->execute(array($description, $_SESSION['user_id']));
?>

<input type="text" name="description" size="70" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable [magic_qoutes](http://php.net/magic_quotes) or change this statement

```
  $description = $_POST['description'];
```

as

```
  $description = stripslashes($_POST['description']);
```

Comment: disable magic_qoutes are not working on some of my input type.. stripslashes work perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like your host has Magic Quotes activated. See the manual on how to disable them: http://php.net/magic_quotes